# Cookie desaparece al recargar el navegador

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express, cookies

Estoy creando un api con express y tengo el siguiente problema: en uno de mi endpoint del signin tengo una parte donde guarda una cookie que guarda el token.

```
const token = generateToken(user);

  res.cookie("x-auth-token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
  });
```

al momento de consumir este endpoint en mi front.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/signin", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "include",
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

se guarda la cookie pero cuando recargo el navegador por algun motivo que desconozco desaparece

Comment: Hola. Creo que en los navegadores basados en chromiun hay una opción para eliminar los datos al recargar la página, ya descartaste esto?

Comment: Hola. Si ya revise todas las configuraciones de mi navegador pero aún tengo el mismo problema lo e intentado con varios navegadores y en diferentes computadoras pero se sigue eliminando

Comment: Probablemente porque el tiempo de expiración lo pusiste como `expires` y es sin la S, solo `expire`... Por lo tanto puede que la cookie se quede sin tiempo de expiración y expire de inmediato.

Comment: Pues ya e intentado hacer el cambio pero aún así no me funciona